# Project Tango Pythagoras: Can't trigger OnXYZijAvailable Callback

Tags: java, android, vuforia, google-project-tango

Developing a Project Tango Android app in the Java API, and I can't get the tablet to trigger an onXYZijAvailable callback, and I'd really like to use the depth data in my application.

Here is my code for setting up the Tango and attaching its listeners:

Upon Tango initialization:

```
try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating TangoPoseHandler Object");
            this.main = main;
            mTango = new Tango(main);
            mConfig = new TangoConfig();
            mConfig = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_CURRENT);
            mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING, true);
            mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
            mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_AUTORECOVERY, true);
            framePairs = new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Log.d("TANGO ERROR", "TangoErrorException");
        }
```

During the activity's onResume():

```
if (!isTangoConnected) {
            main.startActivityForResult(
                    Tango.getRequestPermissionIntent(Tango.PERMISSIONTYPE_MOTION_TRACKING),
                    Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE);
        }
```

Upon Activity result:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY, "Activity Result Triggered");
        if (Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE == requestCode) {
            ((TangoPoseHandler)poseHandler).setup(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

The setup method called:

```
 public void setup(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(main,
                        "This app requires Motion Tracking permission!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                main.finish();
                return;
            }

            try {
                setTangoListeners();
            } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "TANGO ERROR WHEN SETTING LISTENERS");
                Toast.makeText(main, "Tango Error! Restart the app!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                mTango.connect(mConfig);
                isTangoConnected = true;
            } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Tango Service out of date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                Toast.makeText(main.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Tango Error! Restart the app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

The setTangoListeners() method called:

```
private void setTangoListeners() {
        // Select coordinate frame pairs
        framePairs.clear();
        framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
                TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE ,
                TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE ));

        mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener() {

            /**
             * Callback called when new pose data is made available from the Tango
             * @param tangoPoseData
             */
            @Override
            public void onPoseAvailable(final TangoPoseData tangoPoseData) {

                if (tangoPoseData.baseFrame == TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE &&
                        tangoPoseData.targetFrame == TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE ) {


                    float[] transform = new float[16];
                    Matrix.setIdentityM(transform, 0);

                    NVector translationData = new NVector(
                            SCALE_FACTOR * tangoPoseData.getTranslationAsFloats()[TangoPoseData.INDEX_TRANSLATION_X],
                            SCALE_FACTOR * tangoPoseData.getTranslationAsFloats()[TangoPoseData.INDEX_TRANSLATION_Y],
                            SCALE_FACTOR * tangoPoseData.getTranslationAsFloats()[TangoPoseData.INDEX_TRANSLATION_Z]);

                    rotationQuat = new NVector((float) tangoPoseData.rotation[TangoPoseData.INDEX_ROTATION_X],
                            tangoPoseData.getRotationAsFloats()[TangoPoseData.INDEX_ROTATION_Y],
                            tangoPoseData.getRotationAsFloats()[TangoPoseData.INDEX_ROTATION_Z],
                            tangoPoseData.getRotationAsFloats()[TangoPoseData.INDEX_ROTATION_W]);

                    float[] quatMat = new float[16];
                    Matrix.setIdentityM(quatMat, 0);
                    quatMat = quaternionToMatrix(rotationQuat);

                    Matrix.multiplyMM(transform, 0, openGLConversion, 0, quatMat, 0);

                    transform[12] = translationData.getX();
                    transform[13] = translationData.getZ();
                    transform[14] = -1.f * translationData.getY();

                    float[] invertedTransform = new float[16];
                    Matrix.setIdentityM(invertedTransform, 0);

                    Matrix.invertM(invertedTransform, 0, transform, 0);

                    //main.displayMat(invertedTransform);
                    SceneCamera.instance().setEye(translationData);
                    SceneCamera.instance().set(invertedTransform);

                    //main.displayVals(tempPosition, rotationQuat);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Callback called when new depth data is made available from the tango
             *
             * @param tangoXyzIjData
             */
            @Override
            public void onXyzIjAvailable(final TangoXyzIjData tangoXyzIjData) {
                Log.d("Depth Data", "Collected");
                pointCloudBuffer = tangoXyzIjData.xyz;
            }

            /**
             * Callback when new Image Frame is available for capture
             * @param cameraID      ID of the camera who has a fresh frame prepared
             */
            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraID) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFrameAvailable Called");
                // Intentionally left empty
            }

            /**
             * Callback when tango has an issue that needs addressing
             * @param tangoEvent    the event storing the data of the issue
             */
            @Override
            public void onTangoEvent(final TangoEvent tangoEvent) {

            if (tangoEvent.eventKey.equals(TangoEvent.DESCRIPTION_FISHEYE_OVER_EXPOSED) ||
                    tangoEvent.eventKey.equals((TangoEvent.DESCRIPTION_COLOR_OVER_EXPOSED))) {
                sendMessage("The Camera is overexposed. Please try facing somewhere with less direct light.");
            }
            if (tangoEvent.eventKey.equals(TangoEvent.DESCRIPTION_FISHEYE_UNDER_EXPOSED) ||
                    tangoEvent.eventKey.equals((TangoEvent.DESCRIPTION_COLOR_UNDER_EXPOSED))) {
                sendMessage("Fisheye Lens is underexposed. Please try facing somewhere with more light.");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I hate to vomit code like this, but I've been trying on and off for weeks to get the depth sensing to work, but the onXYZijAvailable callback just refuses to be called, and I'm at the end of my rope.

One thing that might be an issue is that the app uses Vuforia for some extra Augmented Reality features, and has access to the color camera and camera preview, but I didn't see anything in the Tango documentation that would suggest that that might cause an issue.

Thanks much to anyone that can help me out.

Comment: Do you get the other callbacks? Is the XyzIj callback the only one that isn't being called?

Comment: I regularly receive the onPoseAvailable callback, but never receive onXYZij or onFrameAvailable

Comment: I posted here a possible answer that helped me solve the exact same thing(I'm not sure if it would help you since I don't see the same problem that I had in your code) but it might be a good reference.